# How to set sha1 hash in cookie on redirect?

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I need to set a sha1 hash in a cookie on redirect that I can check on every further request.

As far as I can see I can only set a Cookie on redirect with a RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^(needCheck)$ /check [L,R=302,CO=myCookie:${sha1(%{myVar})}:.mydomain.com]`

But this is not possible as I have no access to sha1 function in this context. But I can use an external function with a RewriteMap. Something like

`RewriteMap sha1_map prg:/var/www/mydomain/sha1.sh`
`RewriteRule ^(needCheck)$ /check [L,R=302,CO=myCookie:${sha1_map:%{myVar}}:.mydomain.com]`

But I cannot figure out how to write the external function, so that the sha1 hash matches the one generated by Apache. Can someone give me a hint?

Any further requests check the hash with
`<If "sha1('%{myVar}') == ...>`

Or can I achieve this simplier?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself.
Yes, it works right like that. My sha1.sh was wrong.
It should be

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo -n $line | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}'\n
done
```

Then the hash is equal.